# How to write sql for this?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I've tables like this

```
Customer
-ID
-name
-address

Business
-ID
-name
-type

Discount
-ID
-amount
-BusinessID
-position

UsedDiscounts
-CustomerID
-DiscountID
```

Business has many discounts.

User has used many discounts, record of which is in UsedDiscounts.

User can only use discount in order, defined by position. Discount 1, then Discount 2. So even if business has 10 discounts out, the one Customer qualifies for is Position of used discount by that business + 1.

**Goal: get all discounts user qualify for.**

My approach was to do left exclusion join on Discounts and Used Discounts.

So get all discounts minus used ones, then somehow do min on position and get all "qualified" ones. However, I might be able to pull this off in SQL I have no idea how..

Sample Incomplete SQL looks like this

```
SELECT *, min(gd.position)  FROM

(SELECT * FROM "Deals" as d WHERE (d.active = true) AND (d.latitude BETWEEN 40 AND 41) AND (d.longitude BETWEEN -75 AND -70)) AS gd

LEFT JOIN

(SELECT du."DealId" FROM "DealsUsed" AS du WHERE du."CustomerId" = 1) AS bd

ON gd.id = bd."DealId"
WHERE bd."DealId" IS NULL
GROUP BY gd."UserId";
```

gives wrong output

```
Sample data:

Customer
--------
id   name  address
0    Tobby   93903903
1    Emi     3839039
2    Loop    393030

Business
--------
id   name   type
0    Cool   flower
1    Corner car
2    New    deli
3    Side   printing
4    Big    car

Discount
--------
id  amount  businessId  position
0   10       0              0
1   22       3              1
2   10       3              2
3   43       2              0
4   23       5              0
5   10       5              1

Used Discount
----------
customerId    discountId
1              2


outcome for customer 1 , emi, shouuld be 
Discounts
--------
id  amount  businessId  position
0   10       0              0
4   23       5              0
3   43       2              0
5   10       5              1
```

Comment: show sample data and expected result.

Comment: where is the relationship of customer to business? is it discount.position = customer.id ?

Comment: yes, customer relation is only to discount

Comment: but good point maybe that relation ship can be taken out

Comment: Are you sure you wanted to use this `WHERE bd."DealId" IS NULL`? Can't see it in your sample data.

Comment: whole idea is to exclude discounts that have been used

Answer (score 0):

Your left join does not take affect because you use where clause in the second query:

Remove where clause:

```
SELECT *, min(gd.position)  FROM

(SELECT * FROM "Deals" as d WHERE (d.active = true) AND (d.latitude BETWEEN 40 AND 41) AND (d.longitude BETWEEN -75 AND -70)) AS gd

LEFT JOIN

(SELECT du."DealId" FROM "DealsUsed" AS du) AS bd

ON gd.id = bd."DealId"
WHERE bd."DealId" IS NULL
GROUP BY gd."UserId";
```

using `Group by` with `Select *` is not advisable. Just select the fields you need. Something like:

```
SELECT gd."UserId", min(gd.position)  FROM

(SELECT * FROM "Deals" as d WHERE (d.active = true) AND (d.latitude BETWEEN 40 AND 41) AND (d.longitude BETWEEN -75 AND -70)) AS gd

LEFT JOIN

(SELECT du."DealId" FROM "DealsUsed" AS du) AS bd

ON gd.id = bd."DealId"
WHERE bd."DealId" IS NULL
GROUP BY gd."UserId";
```

You can use where clause after on like:

```
SELECT gd."UserId",bd."CustomerId", min(gd.position)  FROM

(SELECT * FROM "Deals" as d WHERE (d.active = true) AND (d.latitude BETWEEN 40 AND 41) AND (d.longitude BETWEEN -75 AND -70)) AS gd

LEFT JOIN

(SELECT du."DealId" FROM "DealsUsed" AS du) AS bd

ON gd.id = bd."DealId"
WHERE bd."DealId" IS NULL and bd."CustomerId" = 1
GROUP BY gd."UserId";
```

Comment: this would remove all deals used by any user, not by a given user. and this still gives an error

Comment: Now show your sample data and your expected output.