# Error: Id must appear in group by clause, Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I've the following sql

```
SELECT *, min(okd.position) FROM

-- all deals
(SELECT * FROM "Deals" as d
WHERE (d.active = true) AND (d.latitude BETWEEN 40 AND 41) AND (d.longitude BETWEEN -75 AND -70)) AS okd

LEFT JOIN

-- used deals
(SELECT * FROM "Deals" as ad INNER JOIN
  (SELECT * FROM "DealsUsed" AS du WHERE du."CustomerId" = 1) AS rd
ON rd."DealId" = ad.id) as dd

--deals that were not used, grouped by user and sorted by position
ON dd."UserId" = okd."UserId" AND dd.position = okd.position
WHERE dd.id IS NULL
GROUP BY okd."UserId";
```

To me it looks like valid sql

Comment: but do you get an error? Where is the problem?

Comment: It might be valid is MySQL, but most likely is not in any other database, such as the one you tagged.

Comment: List your columns.  We can't see what is in `*`.  We can't help you if we can't see what's wrong with your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT *` means "give me all columns" from table(s) involved in the `FROM` clause. I presume that it is not just UserId, but bunch of other columns as well. Which ones? Can't tell, as you `SELECT * FROM "Deals"`. Consider avoiding `SELECT *` anywhere but for *quick & dirty* testing purposes.

Therefore, either enumerate all of them in the `GROUP BY` clause (which you probably don't want), or `SELECT` only UserId along with aggregated column; for example,

```
select okd."UserId", min(okd.position) 
FROM (your current FROM clause)
group by okd."UserId"
```

**[EDIT, based on Oracle (as I have it), but applies to your database too]**

Have a look at the following examples:

This works OK - I'm selecting department number and sum salaries of all employees who work in those departments:

```
SQL> select deptno, sum(sal)
  2  from emp
  3  group by deptno
  4  order by deptno;

    DEPTNO   SUM(SAL)
---------- ----------
        10       8750
        20       6775
        30       9400
```

I'd like to include job as well, i.e. sum salaries per department and job. If I include a new column into the SELECT but don't have it in GROUP BY, it'll fail:

```
SQL> select deptno, job, sum(sal)
  2  from emp
  3  group by deptno
  4  order by deptno;
select deptno, job, sum(sal)
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

Therefore, you have two options:

- one is to revert back to the first query (i.e. remove JOB and have DEPTNO only), or
- include additional column into the GROUP BY clause

---

```
SQL> select deptno, job, sum(sal)
  2  from emp
  3  group by deptno, job
  4  order by deptno, job;

    DEPTNO JOB         SUM(SAL)
---------- --------- ----------
        10 CLERK           1300
        10 MANAGER         2450
        10 PRESIDENT       5000
        20 ANALYST         3000
        20 CLERK            800
        20 MANAGER         2975
        30 CLERK            950
        30 MANAGER         2850
        30 SALESMAN        5600
```

**[A LITTLE BIT MORE]**

Yet another thing: there's a way to aggregate values without using the GROUP BY clause; in Oracle, that's what analytic functions do. I don't know whether there's something like that in the database system you use, but you might check it. Here's an example:

```
SQL> select deptno, ename, job, sum(sal) over (partition by deptno) sum_sal_dept
  2  from emp
  3  order by deptno, job;

    DEPTNO ENAME      JOB       SUM_SAL_DEPT
---------- ---------- --------- ------------
        10 MILLER     CLERK             8750
        10 CLARK      MANAGER           8750
        10 KING       PRESIDENT         8750
        20 FORD       ANALYST           6775
        20 SMITH      CLERK             6775
        20 JONES      MANAGER           6775
        30 JAMES      CLERK             9400
        30 BLAKE      MANAGER           9400
        30 TURNER     SALESMAN          9400
        30 WARD       SALESMAN          9400
        30 ALLEN      SALESMAN          9400
        30 MARTIN     SALESMAN          9400
```

See? Without the GROUP BY clause, I've calculated sum of salaries per departments.

Comment: i actually do want all other columns, i dont understand the need to group?

Comment: I've edited my message by adding an example; have a look. It demonstrates what happens if you do (or do not) include columns (used in SELECT) in GROUP BY  clause.

Comment: ok sorry, so i must have started with what i wanted, what you told me is working but giving wrong output, wrong as in not what i wanted: can you check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137542/how-to-write-sql-for-this

Comment: I reviewed your another question; if you could add some sample data as well as expected output, maybe it would be simpler to assist. Currently, you posted different table names in question and code you wrote, so it is rather misleading. I don't understand what is "Business" table there for. Also, it is getting quite late over here so I'm going to sleep, but will try to have another look tomorrow.

Comment: thanks, basically get all deals that user qualifies for. There is going to be one deal per business for a user. Biz do offer multiple deals, but user can only get them step by step. Deal number is based on position.....
Suppose biz has 5 deals out, with positions `0,1,2,3,4` then if user has used deal with position 0, now user qualifies for `deal.position = 1`, the next number.

My approach was to get all deals by all businesses, delete all deals that user has used, find the lowest position deal per business (why i used group)